# Are variables of this casino game dependent?

Tags: probability, statistics

In a casino a slot machine displays pairs of symbols which are either a **club** or a **spade**.
A player may obtain the following options: double club, double spade, club-spade, or spade-club.

Each entry (club or spade) of the pair is obtained independently.
The club appears with probability $\theta\in(0,1)$ and spade with $1-\theta$.

It is assumed that outcomes of the slot machine are i.i.d.
For $n$ games, we denote $N_c$ the number of times a pair of clubs has been obtained; $N_s$ that of spades and $N_{cs}$ that of club-spade or spade-club.

Are the random variables $N_c$, $N_s$ and $N_{cs}$ independent?

---

So far, I have found the following (hopefully it's correct):

$$\mathbb P(N_c=k)=\left(n,k\right)\theta^{2k}(1-\theta^2)^{n-k}$$

$$\mathbb P(N_s=k)=\left(n,k\right)(1-\theta)^{2k}(1-(1-\theta)^2)^{n-k}$$

$$\mathbb P(N_{cs}=k)=\left(n,k\right)(2\theta(1-\theta))^{k}(1-(2\theta(1-\theta)))^{n-k}$$

where $(n,k)$ means $n$ choose $k$.

But I cannot understand how to show if they are independent or not.
I've tried it through conditional independence but I'm stuck very early.

Comment: Hint: $N_c+N_s+N_{cs} = n$

Comment: Okay, it then means that $\mathbb P(N_c) + \mathbb P(N_s) + \mathbb P(N_{cs})=1$, so I have to show that $1 - \mathbb P(N_c) - \mathbb P(N_s) = \mathbb P(N_{cs})$?

Comment: How could they be independent? If you got $n$ club-club pairs, how many spade-spade pairs did you get?  Also, what does $\theta^*$ mean?

Comment: If $k=n$ for $N_c$, then $0$. But this is ex-post information? Or what don't I understand? Removed $\theta^*$ due to irrelevance.

Comment: If you know that $N_c=n$ then that affects the conditional distribution of $N_s$ and $N_{cs}$.  So they are not independent.  Or say $P(N_c=n, N_s=n)=0 \not = P(N_c=n)P(N_s=n)$

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you!